# How do I set up a virtualenv and set up flask with it?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

I am receiving an error regarding [ImportError: No module named flask]. I also cannot set up a virtualenv to run flask under and was told that running without a virtualenv is not advised. Any help is appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

print(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print("--"*40,"Matrix Active and Running!!!"*4,"--"*40)
    return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: What operating system and python version are you using?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python3.3+ you can use the venv module that ships with python to create a virtual environment.  It might seem really confusing at first, but they really are handy.  I have one for each one of my projects.

Open up your terminal and navigate into your project.

1. Create a virtual environment. This will create a directory called .env in your current directory. This is your virtual environment.

   python -m venv .env
2. To use and install stuff into your virtual environment, you need to "activate" it first. Activating it will tell your interpreter to use this when running your programs etc.

   source .env/bin/activate
3. Now you can install stuff into your virtual environment (Flask, requests, whatever else you need).

Comment: I get the following when I try to open a virtualenv in my folder:                       Eddies-MacBook-Pro-2:hello_Flask EddieAvinashi$ python -m venv .env
/usr/bin/python: No module named venv
Eddies-MacBook-Pro-2:hello_Flask EddieAvinashi$

Comment: You must be using python2.7 @EddieAvinashi